# Do an abbreviated word have to be enclosed by the apostrophe?

Tags: abbreviations, apostrophe, contractions

been searching for a while now so: When omitting parts of words with an apostrophe, do it have to be enclosed by the word?

A good example that helped me answer a few of my own questions was:
[Using apostrophe when abbreviating "recommendations" as "reco's"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29693/using-apostrophe-when-abbreviating-recommendations-as-recos). Let me use that as an example:
Can I simply write ''recommendations'' as reco' and not enclose it like reco's.
Similar examples would be, from Wikipedia, spelling fo’c’s’le, contracted from the nautical term forecastle, can I simply spell it forecas' then move on in the sentence? Doesn't that also cause the word to be possessive, because of the S?

Is there any rule to this or can I also do it with any-thing, like:

> Have you seen my guitar amp'

or (amplifier)

> Have you seen my guitar amp'r

What about simpler words, spyin' or shootin' and so on?

Comment: The use of non-standard spelling does not, per definition, have rules. If you are writing fiction, you choose a style and use it consistently. I recommend to use it with caution as it is likely to irritate your readers.

Comment: The apostrophe is supposed to replace the omitted letters. _Fo'c's'le_ is the standard way of writing the nautical contraction, so why should you need to invent your own version? _Forecas'_ suggests a mispronunciation of _forecast_, like _shootin'_ which is a standard way of representing a particular speech habit, not an abbreviation. Also, the answer in the link you quote suggests not using an apostrophe with familiar abbreviations like _phone_. I would suggest that _amp_ falls into that category.

Comment: @Stefan Though I agree with the rest of your comment "non-standard" does not mean (by definition) that there are no rules for it. It's perfectly possible for a rule to exist which focuses solely on an uncommon (non-standard) spelling. Trikes are non-standard motorbikes, but that doesn't mean that trikes are unregulated.

Comment: I would understand *amp* as short form of amplifier in any context, but *amp'r* would throw me off totally.

Comment: Sorry, AJ; if you’re trying to use *reco’s* then, by definition, you’re insisting the choice in abbreviations be changed.

Those who insist *reco* works might be able to explain their rules. Most of us know there is no *standard* abbreviation for *recommendation*; if there were it would prolly be *rec(c)s, with no apostrophe.* 

If you want to insist, what d’you think the basic rules of apostrophes say, please?

There’s no question of anything being omitted. If it doesn’t belong there, that’s all. If it does, it should be included; no kind of *omission*.